# Officiating speech or official speech

Tags: common-word

Is there such a word phrase called officiating speech or is it an official speech? The speech is delivered in order to officiate a ceremony. I've heard of inaugural speeches, though. I'm not sure if an inaugural speech means to officiate a ceremony or an event.

Many thanks

Comment: Hello, Kingston.  On ELU, questions lacking reasonable research (even where this does not provide a satisfactory answer) may be put on hold. How often do the strings "official speech" and "officiating speech" appear on the internet (and do most of  the examples seem to be from native speakers), or in Google Ngrams? // You may also consider it useful to read this usage note at [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/officiate) advising that many consider the transitive use of _officiate_ unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct phrase is "official speech". A person *[officiates](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/officiate)* at an event when they are in charge of it, or preside over it. An *inaugural speech* is a specific type of official speech that is made when something is being *[inaugurated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inaugurate)* - i.e. when something is beginning, whether that be a person's term in a political office, the creation of a new agency/department, or a new program or policy.

So it is possible, for instance, that one politician could officiate during an official speech by another politician, if the former were in charge of organizing the speaking event, introducing the speaker, etc (perhaps while the latter was being inaugurated ...).

Comment: This looks like a decent answer. Do you have any references you can add (thefreedictionary.com is sometimes a good place to start). References improve your answer by making it more objective and less opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks Pam. I added some links to Oxford dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. The reason I posed this question is because my school is organizing an English Language Carnival where a guest of honour will be invited to give a speech, and a senior English teacher was writing a programme book for it. Therein, she wrote 'officiating speech'. I told her I'd had never heard of such compound noun before, and said it should probably be 'official speech', but she said it's wrong and maintained 'officiating speech'. To me, such a simple grammar mistake can cause a huge embarrassment.

A second language user of English here.

Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Kinston AG.  You're not supposed to post comments as answers.  As soon as you get enough reputation, you'll be allowed to post comments.